# Number vs Percent problem

Tags: apex, decimal

I am seeing some odd behaviour with Numeric vs Percent fields.

I have two fields, on separate objects:

- Percentage Commission on Object A - Number(15,3)
- Percentage Commission on Object B - Percent(3,4)

So, in Object A I am seeing values like 0.05 to represent 5% and then when these values are copied (via Apex) to Object B I am seeing the value 5.

This is all working as expected in both Packaging org and Sandbox, but as soon as deployed to Production I now get 0.5 in Object A and also 0.5 in Object B so instead of some a salesman getting 5% commission, they're only getting 0.05% (I know, poor them ;).

This is the line of Apex that performs the copy each 'line' is an instance of Object A, detail is an instance of Object B:

```
detail.Percent_Commission__c = (Decimal)line.get('Rep_Percentage__c');
```

Am I just missing something really obvious or is there something else at play? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the relevant `Apex` code?

Comment: i've copied the relevant line, seems like its more environmental to me since its only different on Production

Comment: Have you verified that the types match up between environments for both fields? Which field is percent and which is number?

Comment: Yes, all same across all environments. `Rep_Percentage__c` is Number(15,3) `Percent_Commission__c` is Percent(3,4)

Comment: Is the `Apex Class` in question the same `API Version` in both?

Comment: Its part of a managed package so I think the answer is yes by default

Comment: field type decimal places?

Comment: All fields are consistent across all 3 orgs, the issue only occurs in Production